# How can I disable each API call being logged to directory as new .log file?

Tags: python, logging

Each time I run my script accessing an API, it is logged as a new and separate .log file in the directory. Anyone know how to prevent this to reduce clutter?
Code linking to API:

```
import meraki
import os

with open('meraki_api_key','r') as f:
    meraki_api_key = f.readline().strip()
os.environ['MERAKI-API-KEY'] = meraki_api_key

dashboard = meraki.DashboardAPI(meraki_api_key)
```

[image: Logs in directory]

Have searched for a solution but can't find anything addressing this specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want any log files passing the parameter `suppress_logging=True` should help, i.e.,

```
meraki.DashboardAPI(meraki_api_key, suppress_logging=True)
```